# Get the equivalent DataprocCreateBatchOperator operator for Azure airflow operator

Tags: python, azure, google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have 3 operators imported from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc

1. `DataprocCreateBatchOperator`
2. `DataprocDeleteBatchOperator`
3. `DataprocGetBatchOperator`

Need the same kind-of operators for Azure.
Can please someone look into this or I have to create a new operator ?

Comment: `Dataproc` is a managed cluster in `GCP`, do you want running `Spark` job in `Azure` ? In which cluster please ?

Comment: Dataproc supports creating a batch workload.

I want for batch only

Comment: Which cluster will you use on `Azure` for your `Spark` jobs ?

Comment: can you check the other comment

Comment: It seems like you're trying to run spark jobs on an Azure cluster; is that correct?

Comment: can you check the code in the answers i am new to airflow so i am not sure its a cluster job or a batch job please seriously guide me in this i am literally stuck

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Do you have a Dataproc cluster in GCP, and you're trying to use Airflow to orchestrate Apache Spark jobs?

Comment: i want an operator just like DataprocCreateBatchOperator (used for creating a batch) but for azure. i have the batch but i need an operator from azure side or create a new one which will create a new batch

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure` provider package equivalent for Dataproc operators would be [Azure Synapse Operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure/stable/operators/azure_synapse.html).

Specifically, the `AzureSynapseRunSparkBatchOperator` allows users to "execute a spark application within Synapse Analytics".

If you're running Spark jobs on Azure Databricks, there are also several [Databricks Operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-databricks/stable/operators/index.html) that might be able to help.

---

Here's an example `PythonOperator` (via [Taskflow API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html)) that uses the `AzureSynapseHook`. Note that I didn't test this, and I'm just using this as a demonstration of what it might look like:

```
@task()
def cancel_spark_job(job_id: str):
    hook = AzureSynapseHook(azure_synapse_conn_id="your_conn_id")
    if hook.wait_for_job_run_status(job_id, expected_statuses=("error", "dead", "killed"):
        hook.cancel_job_run(job_id)
```

This task will wait for a spark job to enter a status of "error", "dead", or "killed" or timeout. If the spark job enters one of the statuses previously mentioned, it will cancel the job. Again, this is just for a demonstration of how to use the `AzureSynapseHook` within a `PythonOperator`, and I'm not sure if it would work or if it even makes sense to implement it this way.

Comment: ok i think AzureSynapseRunSparkBatchOperator this can create a batch but how to get operators like DataprocGetBatchOperator, DataprocDeleteBatchOperator ?

Comment: It seems like you can either create a custom operator using the [AzureSynapseHook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure/stable/_api/airflow/providers/microsoft/azure/hooks/synapse/index.html#airflow.providers.microsoft.azure.hooks.synapse.AzureSynapseHook) or use the AzureSynapseHook in a PythonOperator to interact with Spark jobs.

Comment: can you tell me some examples or references on how can i do that?

Comment: There's lots of documentation on both [writing custom operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html) and using the [PythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html).

Comment: ok so if i am using AzureSynapseRunSparkBatchOperator then how can i use AzureSynapseHook ? i think both are different so how will they be connected ?

Comment: What *specifically* are you trying to do? Any Hook can be used in a custom operator or in a PythonOperator to interact with your spark jobs. The AzureSynapseHook has methods like `get_job_run_status()` to monitor jobs or `cancel_job_run(job_id)` to cancel spark jobs, and you can bake these into a custom operator or into a PythonOperator task. It's hard to give you an accurate answer without knowing what you're actually trying to accomplish. Consider bringing the discussion [to the Airflow community slack](https://apache-airflow-slack.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Thank for the help. I have used them using Python Operator but for cancel_job_run(job_id) job_id is required which I don't know how I will get. Need guidance for that

Comment: Can you store the job ID in an [xcom](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html) or [Airflow Variable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/variable.html)?

Answer (score 0):

@Mazlum Tosun

For GCP in my code DataprocCreateBatchOperator used like this:-

```
create_batch = DataprocCreateBatchOperator(
    task_id="CREATE_BATCH",
    batch={
            "pyspark_batch": {
                "main_python_file_uri": f"gs://{ARTIFACT_BUCKET}/spark-jobs/main.py",
                "args": app_args,
                "python_file_uris": [
                    f"gs://{ARTIFACT_BUCKET}/spark-jobs/jobs.zip",
                    f"gs://{ARTIFACT_BUCKET}/spark-jobs/libs.zip"
                ],
                "jar_file_uris": test_jars,
                "file_uris": [
                    f"gs://{ARTIFACT_BUCKET}/config/params.yaml"
                ]
            },
            "environment_config": {
                "peripherals_config": {
                    "spark_history_server_config": {}
                }
            }
        },
        region=REGION,batch_id=batch_id_str,)
```